# Backtesting Trading Strategy in R using quantmod: Function and for loop within a Function

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using R, quantmod and Performanceanalystics packages. As part of a backtesting strategy, I am trying to create a signal/holdings vector that tells me whether I should buy/sell/hold a stock, based on the value of RSI. If RSI<30, buy (so holdings increases by 1), if RSI is between 30 & 50, don't do anything (so holdings remain the same as yesterday). If RSI>=50, sell everything (so holdings become zero). Thereafter, use the dailyReturn() function from Performanceanalytics to calculate and generate a graph of returns.

Note that RSI() is a function that takes "price" and "day", and dailyReturn() function also takes "price"

I have been able to do perfectly fine with the following code below.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("IBM", src= "yahoo", from = "2000-01-01", to ="2015-09-25")

rsi<-RSI(Cl(IBM),14)
rsi<-lag(rsi,1)
rsi[is.na(rsi)] <- 0 

holdings1 <-c() #initialize the vector
holdings1[1:14+1]<-0  #Not holding any shares of IBM from 1st to the 15th day
for (i in 14+2: length(Cl(IBM))){ #assume start buying from the 16th day onwards since we are using RSI where n=14
 if (rsi[i]<30){ #if RSI<30, we buy one share of IBM
  holdings1[i]<-holdings1[i-1]+1  
  } else if (rsi[i]>50){ # if RSI>50, we sell all holdings
  holdings1[i]<-0
 } else 
   holdings1[i]<- holdings1[i-1] # remains the same: if 30<=RSI<=50 we don't do anything, so same holdings as prior
 }
size1<-reclass(holdings1,Cl(IBM))
ret1<-dailyReturn(Cl(IBM))*size1
charts.PerformanceSummary(ret1)
```

But I am required to create a function called "size1()" that takes in "price" and "day" (Prof says, and I don't do computing). When I try to that, RStudio tells me "Error in lag(rsi, 1) : object 'rsi' not found". Why is that? Is it not legal to create a function or a vector in a function? Or should I structure my code in a different way from the first one above? The code with function(price,day) is below:

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("IBM", src= "yahoo", from = "2000-01-01", to ="2015-09-25") #download IBM, from the stipulated range of dates

size1<-function(price,day){
  ris<-RSI(price,day)
  ris<-lag(rsi,1)
  rsi[is.na(rsi)] <- 0
  holdings1<-c()
  holdings1[1:day+1]<-0
 for (i in day+2: length(price)){ #assume start buying from the 15th day onwards since we are using RSI, n=14
  if (rsi[i]<30){ #if RSI<30, we buy one share of IBM
    holdings1[i]<-holdings1[i-1]+1  
  } else if (rsi[i]<50){ # if 30<RSI<50, we don't buy or sell, so that the holdings does not change
    holdings1[i]<-holdings1[i-1]
  } else 
    holdings1[i]<-0 # sell all if RSI>50
  size<-reclass(holdings1,price)
  }
}

ret1<-dailyReturn(Cl(IBM))*size1(Cl(IBM),14)
charts.PerformanceSummary(ret1)
```

Comment: You have a spelling error in your code: `ris` is not `rsi`.

Comment: Hi, just editted, its still not working.
       `ret1<-dailyReturn(Cl(IBM))*size1(Cl(IBM),14)`
       (Error in `[.xts`(rsi, i) : subscript out of bounds)                   `charts.PerformanceSummary(ret1)`
       (Error in inherits(x, "xts") : object 'ret1' not found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`day+2:length(price)` isn't what you expect. `:` has precedence over `+` (see `?Syntax`).  It evaluates to `day + (2:length(price))`.  You want `(day+2):length(price)`. Also note that xts objects are a matrix with an `index` attribute, and a matrix is just a vector with a `dim` attribute. Calling `length` on a matrix returns the total number of observations (the `length` of the vector). You should use `nrow` instead.

It's also good practice to pre-allocate the entire result vector before the `for` loop. Your current code appends to `holdings` every time you call `holdings[i] <-` when `i` is larger than the current length of `holdings`.

Also, your function currently does not return anything. It looks like you intend to return the `size` object. Note that you do not need to re-create that object at every loop iteration.

```
size1 <- function (price, day) {
    rsi <- RSI(price, day)
    rsi <- lag(rsi, 1)
    rsi[is.na(rsi)] <- 0
    holdings1 <- integer(nrow(price))
    # assume start buying from the 15th day onwards,
    # since we are using RSI, n=14
    for (i in (day+1):nrow(price)) {
        if (rsi[i] < 30) {
            # if RSI<30, we buy one share of IBM
            holdings1[i] <- holdings1[i - 1] + 1
        }
        else if (rsi[i] < 50) {
            # if 30<RSI<50, we don't buy or sell,
            # so that the holdings does not change
            holdings1[i] <- holdings1[i - 1]
        } else {
            # sell all if RSI>50
            holdings1[i] <- 0
        }
    }
    reclass(holdings1, price)
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! :) It worked. I am not so good with distinguishing between stuff like c(), length() and nrow(), but I can see now that nrow() is the better one to use. I think I will get better with more practice. Thanks again!

Comment: @SiangEeEo: Also note that calling `nrow` on a vector will return `NULL`, so it's safer to use `NROW` (and `NCOL`) if you're unsure.